# Wordpress Theme PHP help needed

Tags: php, wordpress, header, blogs

I am creating my website using a premium Wordpress theme, when I use a custom theme header the theme automatically places my blog header and social icons inside my full width feature graphic which I upload within the post. See here for an example: http://www.ravagedesign.com/freebies/greyice-hd-launcher-theme-icon-pack-released/

I would like to make it so that header and social icons appear below the full width graphic like this: http://www.ravagedesign.com/freebies/greylime-hd-launcher-theme-icon-pack-released/
(note that I have achieved this using a slider plugin which is not an option due to increase page load time and poor organisation it would create.

I have narrowed down the section of code relating to the header/social icons within my functions.php file and would like help with modifying it to display how I want as I have little understanding of php.

functions.php section relating to custom header:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
# Custom page header
#-----------------------------------------------------------------# 

if ( !function_exists( 'nectar_page_header' ) ) {
    function nectar_page_header($postid) {

        global $options;
        global $post;
        global $nectar_theme_skin;

        $bg = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_bg', true);
        $bg_color = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_bg_color', true);
        $font_color = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_font_color', true);
        $parallax_bg = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_parallax', true);
        $title = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_title', true);
        $subtitle = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_subtitle', true);
        $height = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_bg_height', true); 
        $page_template = get_post_meta($postid, '_wp_page_template', true); 
        $display_sortable = get_post_meta($postid, 'nectar-metabox-portfolio-display-sortable', true);
        $inline_filters = (!empty($options['portfolio_inline_filters']) && $options['portfolio_inline_filters'] == '1') ? '1' : '0';
        $filters_id = (!empty($options['portfolio_inline_filters']) && $options['portfolio_inline_filters'] == '1') ? 'portfolio-filters-inline' : 'portfolio-filters';
        $text_align = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_page_header_alignment', true); 
        $fullscreen_header = (!empty($options['blog_header_type']) && $options['blog_header_type'] == 'fullscreen' && is_singular('post')) ? true : false;
        $bottom_shadow = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_bottom_shadow', true); 
        $bg_overlay = get_post_meta($postid, '_nectar_header_overlay', true); 

        (!empty($display_sortable) && $display_sortable == 'on') ? $display_sortable = '1' : $display_sortable = '0';

        //incase no title is entered for portfolio, still show the filters
        if( $page_template == 'template-portfolio.php' && empty($title)) $title = get_the_title($post->ID);

        if( !empty($bg) || !empty($bg_color) ) {  

        (empty($bg)) ? $social_img_src = 'none' : $social_img_src = $bg;
        (empty($bg)) ? $bg = 'none' : $bg = 'url('.$bg.')';
        (empty($bg_color)) ? $bg_color = '#000' : $bg_color = $bg_color;
        $height = (!empty($height)) ? preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $height) : $height;
        $not_loaded_class = ($nectar_theme_skin != 'ascend') ? "not-loaded" : null;     
        $fullscreen_class = ($fullscreen_header == true) ? "fullscreen-header" : null;
        $bottom_shadow_class = ($bottom_shadow == 'on') ? " bottom-shadow": null;
        $bg_overlay_class = ($bg_overlay == 'on') ? " bg-overlay": null;
        $ajax_page_loading = (!empty($options['ajax-page-loading']) && $options['ajax-page-loading'] == '1') ? true : false;

        $wrapper_height_style = ($fullscreen_header == true && ($post->post_type == 'post' && is_single()) || $ajax_page_loading == false) ?  null : 'style="height: '.$height.'px;"';

        if(!empty($parallax_bg) && $parallax_bg == 'on') { echo '<div id="page-header-wrap" class="'.$fullscreen_class.'" '.$wrapper_height_style.'>'; } ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $not_loaded_class . ' ' . $fullscreen_class . $bottom_shadow_class . $bg_overlay_class; ?>" id="page-header-bg" data-alignment="<?php echo (!empty($text_align)) ? $text_align : 'left' ; ?>" data-parallax="<?php echo (!empty($parallax_bg) && $parallax_bg == 'on') ? '1' : '0'; ?>" data-height="<?php echo (!empty($height)) ? $height : '350'; ?>" style="background-color: <?php echo $bg_color?>; background-image: <?php echo nectar_options_img($bg); ?>; height: <?php echo $height;?>px;">


            <div class="container"> 

                    <?php 
                    if($post->ID != 0 && $post->post_type && $post->post_type == 'portfolio') { ?>

                    <div class="row project-title">
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="col span_6 section-title <?php if(empty($options['portfolio_social']) || $options['portfolio_social'] == 0 || empty($options['portfolio_date']) || $options['portfolio_date'] == 0 ) echo 'no-date'?>">

                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                        <?php 
                        $options = get_option('salient'); 

                        $back_to_all_override = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nectar-metabox-portfolio-parent-override', true);
                        if(empty($back_to_all_override)) $back_to_all_override = 'default';

                        //attempt to find parent portfolio page - if unsuccessful default to main portfolio page
                        global $post;
                        $terms = get_the_terms($post->id,"project-type");
                        $project_cat = null;
                        $portfolio_link = null; 

                        if(empty($terms)) $terms = array('1' => (object) array('name' => 'nothing'));

                         foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            $project_cat = strtolower($term->name);
                         }

                         $page = get_page_by_title_search($project_cat);
                         if(empty($page)) $page = array( '0' => (object) array('ID' => 'nothing'));

                         $page_link = verify_portfolio_page($page[0]->ID);

                         //if a page has been found for the category
                         if(!empty($page_link) && $back_to_all_override == 'default') {
                            $portfolio_link = $page_link; 

                         ?>

                             <div id="portfolio-nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="all-items"><a href="<?php echo $portfolio_link; ?>"><i class="icon-salient-back-to-all"></i></a></li>               
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="controls">                                 
                                    <li id="prev-link"><?php be_next_post_link('%link','<i class="icon-salient-left-arrow-thin"></i>',TRUE, null,'project-type'); ?></li>
                                    <li id="next-link"><?php be_previous_post_link('%link','<i class="icon-salient-right-arrow-thin"></i>',TRUE, null, 'project-type'); ?></li> 
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                    <?php  } 

                         //if no category page exists
                         else {

                            $portfolio_link = get_portfolio_page_link(get_the_ID()); 
                            if(!empty($options['main-portfolio-link'])) $portfolio_link = $options['main-portfolio-link']; 

                            if($back_to_all_override != 'default') $portfolio_link = get_page_link($back_to_all_override); ?>

                            <div id="portfolio-nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="all-items"><a href="<?php echo $portfolio_link; ?>"><i class="icon-salient-back-to-all"></i></a></li>  
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="controls">                                       
                                    <li id="prev-link"><?php next_post_link('%link','<i class="icon-salient-left-arrow-thin"></i>'); ?></li>
                                    <li id="next-link"><?php previous_post_link('%link','<i class="icon-salient-right-arrow-thin"></i>'); ?></li> 
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                     <?php } ?>

                    </div>
                </div> 

            </div><!--/row-->







                    <?php } elseif($post->ID != 0 && $post->post_type == 'post' && is_single() ) { 

                        // also set as an img for social sharing/
                        if($social_img_src != 'none') echo '<img class="hidden-social-img" src="'.$social_img_src.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';

                        ?>

                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span_6 section-title blog-title">
                            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                             <?php if(($post->post_type == 'post' && is_single()) && $fullscreen_header == true) { ?>
                                <div class="author-section">
                                    <span class="meta-author vcard author">  
                                        <?php if (function_exists('get_avatar')) { echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), 100 ); }?>
                                    </span> 
                                    <div class="avatar-post-info">
                                        <span class="fn"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
                                        <span class="meta-date date updated"><i><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></i></span>
                                     </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php if($fullscreen_header != true) { ?>

                                <div id="single-below-header">
                                    <span class="meta-author vcard author"><span class="fn"><?php echo __('By', NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></span> 
                                    <?php if( !empty($options['blog_social']) && $options['blog_social'] == 1) { ?>
                                        <span class="meta-date date updated"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <span class="meta-category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
                                    <span class="meta-comment-count"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number( __('No Comments', NECTAR_THEME_NAME), __('One Comment ', NECTAR_THEME_NAME), __('% Comments', NECTAR_THEME_NAME) ); ?></a></span>

                                </div><!--/single-below-header-->

                                <div id="single-meta" data-sharing="<?php echo ( !empty($options['blog_social']) && $options['blog_social'] == 1 ) ? '1' : '0'; ?>">
                                    <ul>

                                        <?php if( empty($options['blog_social']) || $options['blog_social'] == 0 ) { ?>

                                                <li>
                                                    <?php echo '<span class="n-shortcode">'.nectar_love('return').'</span>'; ?>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                                                </li>

                                        <?php } ?>

                                    </ul>

                                    <?php if( !empty($options['blog_social']) && $options['blog_social'] == 1 ) { 

                                           echo '<div class="nectar-social">';

                                           echo '<span class="n-shortcode">'.nectar_love('return').'</span>';

                                            //facebook
                                            if(!empty($options['blog-facebook-sharing']) && $options['blog-facebook-sharing'] == 1) { 
                                                echo "<a class='facebook-share nectar-sharing' href='#' title='".__('Share this', NECTAR_THEME_NAME)."'> <i class='icon-facebook'></i> <span class='count'></span></a>";
                                            }
                                            //twitter
                                            if(!empty($options['blog-twitter-sharing']) && $options['blog-twitter-sharing'] == 1) {
                                                echo "<a class='twitter-share nectar-sharing' href='#' title='".__('Tweet this', NECTAR_THEME_NAME)."'> <i class='icon-twitter'></i> <span class='count'></span></a>";
                                            }
                                            //google plus
                                            if(!empty($options['blog-google-plus-sharing']) && $options['blog-google-plus-sharing'] == 1) {
                                                echo "<a class='google-plus-share nectar-sharing-alt' href='#' title='".__('Share this', NECTAR_THEME_NAME)."'> <i class='icon-google-plus'></i> <span class='count'> ".GetGooglePlusShares(get_permalink($post->ID))." </span></a>";
                                            }

                                            //linkedIn
                                            if(!empty($options['blog-linkedin-sharing']) && $options['blog-linkedin-sharing'] == 1) {
                                                echo "<a class='linkedin-share nectar-sharing' href='#' title='".__('Share this', NECTAR_THEME_NAME)."'> <i class='icon-linkedin'></i> <span class='count'> </span></a>";
                                            }
                                            //pinterest
                                            if(!empty($options['blog-pinterest-sharing']) && $options['blog-pinterest-sharing'] == 1) {
                                                echo "<a class='pinterest-share nectar-sharing' href='#' title='".__('Pin this', NECTAR_THEME_NAME)."'> <i class='icon-pinterest'></i> <span class='count'></span></a>";
                                            }

                                          echo '</div>';

                                        }
                                    ?>

                                </div><!--/single-meta-->

                            <?php } //end if theme skin default ?>

                        </div><!--/section-title-->
                    </div><!--/row-->





                    <?php //default 
                    } else { ?>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span_6">
                            <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
                            <span class="subheader"><?php echo $subtitle; ?></span>
                        </div>

                        <?php // portfolio filters
                            if( $page_template == 'template-portfolio.php' && $display_sortable == '1' && $inline_filters == '0') { ?>
                            <div id="<?php echo $filters_id;?>">
                                    <a href="#" data-sortable-label="<?php echo (!empty($options['portfolio-sortable-text'])) ? $options['portfolio-sortable-text'] :'Sort Portfolio'; ?>" id="sort-portfolio"><span><?php echo (!empty($options['portfolio-sortable-text'])) ? $options['portfolio-sortable-text'] : __('Sort Portfolio',NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?></span> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a> 
                                <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#" data-filter="*"><?php echo __('All', NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?></a></li>
                                   <?php wp_list_categories(array('title_li' => '', 'taxonomy' => 'project-type', 'show_option_none'   => '', 'walker' => new Walker_Portfolio_Filter())); ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                      </div>


                <?php } ?>



            </div>


             <?php if(($post->ID != 0 && $post->post_type == 'post' && is_single()) && $fullscreen_header == true) { ?>
                <a href="#" class="section-down-arrow"><i class="icon-salient-down-arrow icon-default-style"> </i></a>
            <?php } ?>


        </div>


       <?php if(!empty($parallax_bg) && $parallax_bg == 'on') { echo '</div>';  } ?>


        <?php } else if( !empty($title)) { ?>

            <div class="row page-header-no-bg" data-alignment="<?php echo (!empty($text_align)) ? $text_align : 'left' ; ?>">
                <div class="container"> 
                    <div class="col span_12 section-title">
                        <h1><?php echo $title; ?><?php if(!empty($subtitle)) echo '<span>' . $subtitle . '</span>'; ?></h1>

                        <?php // portfolio filters
                        if( $page_template == 'template-portfolio.php' && $display_sortable == '1' && $inline_filters == '0') { ?>
                        <div id="<?php echo $filters_id;?>">

                            <a href="#" data-sortable-label="<?php echo (!empty($options['portfolio-sortable-text'])) ? $options['portfolio-sortable-text'] :'Sort Portfolio'; ?>" id="sort-portfolio"><span><?php echo (!empty($options['portfolio-sortable-text'])) ? $options['portfolio-sortable-text'] : __('Sort Portfolio',NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?></span> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a> 

                            <ul>
                               <li><a href="#" data-filter="*"><?php echo __('All', NECTAR_THEME_NAME); ?></a></li>
                               <?php wp_list_categories(array('title_li' => '', 'taxonomy' => 'project-type', 'show_option_none'   => '', 'walker' => new Walker_Portfolio_Filter())); ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>

       <?php }

    }
}


function using_page_header($post_id){

     global $post; 
     global $woocommerce; 

     if($woocommerce && is_shop() || $woocommerce && is_product_category() || $woocommerce && is_product_tag()) {
        $header_title = get_post_meta(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'), '_nectar_header_title', true);
        $header_bg = get_post_meta(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'), '_nectar_header_bg', true);
        $header_bg_color = get_post_meta(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'), '_nectar_header_bg_color', true);
        $disable_effect = get_post_meta(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'), '_disable_transparent_header', true);
        $force_effect = null;
     } 
     else if(is_home() || is_archive()){
        $header_title = get_post_meta(get_option('page_for_posts'), '_nectar_header_title', true);
        $header_bg = get_post_meta(get_option('page_for_posts'), '_nectar_header_bg', true); 
        $header_bg_color = get_post_meta(get_option('page_for_posts'), '_nectar_header_bg_color', true); 
        $disable_effect = get_post_meta(get_option('page_for_posts'), '_disable_transparent_header', true);
        $force_effect = null;
     }  else {
        $header_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nectar_header_title', true);
        $header_bg = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nectar_header_bg', true); 
        $header_bg_color = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nectar_header_bg_color', true); 
        $disable_effect = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_disable_transparent_header', true);
        $force_effect = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_force_transparent_header', true);
     }

    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

    $using_applicable_shortcode = 0;

    if ( preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches )  && array_key_exists( 0, $matches ))  {

        if($matches[0][0]){
            if( strpos($matches[0][0],'nectar_slider') !== false && strpos($matches[0][0],'full_width="true"') !== false) {

                if(empty($header_title)) $using_applicable_shortcode = 1;

            } else {
                $using_applicable_shortcode = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    //alternate header style
    global $options;
    if(!empty($options['blog_header_type']) && $options['blog_header_type'] == 'fullscreen' && is_singular('post'))  $using_applicable_shortcode = 1;

    //incase of search / tax / removing effect
    if(is_search() || is_tax() || $disable_effect == 'on') { $using_applicable_shortcode = 0; $header_bg = 0; $header_bg_color = 0; }

    //stop effect from WooCommerce single pages
    global $woocommerce; 
    if($woocommerce && is_product()) { $using_applicable_shortcode = 0; $header_bg = 0; $header_bg_color = 0; }

    //if forcing effect
    if($force_effect == 'on' && (!is_search() && !is_tax()) ) { $using_applicable_shortcode = 1; }

    $the_verdict = (!empty($header_bg_color) || !empty($header_bg) || $using_applicable_shortcode) ? true : false;

    return $the_verdict;

}


function using_nectar_slider(){

    global $post; 
    global $woocommerce;

    if($woocommerce && is_shop() || $woocommerce && is_product_category() || $woocommerce && is_product_tag()) {
        $header_title = get_post_meta(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'), '_nectar_header_title', true);
        $header_bg = get_post_meta(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'), '_nectar_header_bg', true);
        $header_bg_color = get_post_meta(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'), '_nectar_header_bg_color', true);
     } 
     else if(is_home() || is_archive()){
        $header_title = get_post_meta(get_option('page_for_posts'), '_nectar_header_title', true);
        $header_bg = get_post_meta(get_option('page_for_posts'), '_nectar_header_bg', true); 
        $header_bg_color = get_post_meta(get_option('page_for_posts'), '_nectar_header_bg_color', true); 
     }  else {
        $header_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nectar_header_title', true);
        $header_bg = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nectar_header_bg', true); 
        $header_bg_color = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nectar_header_bg_color', true); 
     }

    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
    $using_fullwidth_slider = 0;

    if ( preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches )  && array_key_exists( 0, $matches ))  {

        if($matches[0][0]){

            if( strpos($matches[0][0],'nectar_slider') !== false && strpos($matches[0][0],'full_width="true"') !== false 
            || strpos($matches[0][0],' type="full_width_content"') !== false && strpos($matches[0][0],'nectar_slider') !== false && strpos($matches[0][0],'[vc_column width="1/1"') !== false ) {

                $using_fullwidth_slider = 1;

            } else {

                $using_fullwidth_slider = 0;

            }
        }

    }

    //incase of search
    if(is_search() || is_tax()) $using_fullwidth_slider = 0;

    //stop effect from WooCommerce single pages
    global $woocommerce; 
    if($woocommerce && is_product()) $using_fullwidth_slider = 0; 

    $the_verdict = (empty($header_title) && empty($header_bg) && empty($header_bg_color) && $using_fullwidth_slider) ? true : false;

    return $the_verdict;
}
```

Comment: Please narrow down your problem; e.g. by inspecting your page with Chrome Dev Tools or the like and seeing what's causing the misalignment. Just posting all your code and expecting people to "mind-debug" through it won't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you had read the question you would see there is no problem, the code needs restructing/arranging, because I lack the knowledge with php I do not want to miss out important elements within the code so have supplied it all.

Figured this would be better than pasting not enough code which normally happens, if you dont like it dont answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in your site the div container for the blog header and social icons is nested within the div with id="page-header-bg" when it should be within the div with class "container-wrap".

It looks like this is done within your theme so the best thing to do is to copy the header code from "greyLIME HD Launcher Theme" and then replace the word LIME with ICE and the respective social links

Comment: thanks for giving me a constructive answer Shaf, looked up these div names and worked out what sections of code to swap around in both files and have it working as intended now.